# Faster SendKeys C#

Tags: c#, io

I have a handheld Windows Embedded Compact Edition bluetooth device submimtting data to PC application that needs to type the information into a Windows 8.1 computer. The longest strings are about 128 characters long. In an ideal world I would get the device to just simulate a Bluetooth keyboard, but working out how to do that is beyond me for now.

As much as I consider it a crime to use SendKeys, I have had to use `SendKeys.SendWait` to transmit the data to keyboard. I was unable to use `SendKeys.Send` as this program runs in system notification area, and I get error message:

***SendKeys cannot run inside this application because the application is not handling Windows messages.

Either change the application to handle messages, or use the SendKeys.SendWait method.***

Unfortunately for long strings `SendKeys.SendWait` is quite slow, you can see the characters being typed out gradually.

It is a requirement to simulate the keyboard input faster.

It is OK if we destroy user clipboard in this scenario; as these are special purpose machines not used for any other task. In my testing I found clipboard much faster. Unfortunately sometimes the data sends special keyboard controls (i.e. Ctrl/Alt/F2 etc) which do not work via Clipboard.

So what I currently do is send bulk of data via clipboard, and separately send any special characters via `SendKeys`, typically there is only 4 of these special characters at most per data sent.

In my testing this is improving speeds from ~200 ms to type the text, to ~50ms, a noticeable improvement.

Unfortunately the code got way more complex and ugly.

While this works, I am concerned I may not have thought of all the scenarios that will break it.

Some points:

The following must be sent by `SendKeys`:

- Special keypress is +, ^, % followed by either one character or {string of characters}
- Special keypress can also be defined as {}

Anything else is being sent via Clipboard.

- There is never any escaped { or } being sent

Code example:

```
private static void QuickSend(string message)
        {
            // these "SPECIAL" characters can be sent via clipboard, so replace them with clipboard version
            message = message.Replace("{ENTER}", "\r\n");
            message = message.Replace("{TAB}", "\t");

            // stores messages in order to be sent to keyboard
            List<string> messages = new List<string>();

            // these characters are special keypresses that can't be sent via clipboard
            char[] specialChars = { '+', '^', 
'%', 

'~', '{' };
            for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
            {
                int nextSpecialCharIndex = message.IndexOfAny(specialChars, i);

                // no more special characters, use remaining string as is
                if (nextSpecialCharIndex == -1)
                {
                    messages.Add(message.Substring(i));
                    i = message.Length;
                }
                else
                {
                    // if the current character is not the special character
                    // add text up until this special character occurs
                    if (nextSpecialCharIndex != i)
                    {
                        messages.Add(message.Substring(i, nextSpecialCharIndex - i));
                    }

                    // check we are not end of string
                    if (nextSpecialCharIndex < message.Length - 1)
                    {
                        // if special character is brace, send text from current brace to end brace
                        if (message.Substring(nextSpecialCharIndex, 1) == "{")
                        {
                            int endBraceIndex = message.IndexOf('}', i);
                            if (endBraceIndex == -1)
                            {
                                // no end brace - just send remaining text
                                messages.Add(message.Substring(nextSpecialCharIndex));
                                i = message.Length;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                messages.Add(message.Substring(nextSpecialCharIndex, endBraceIndex - nextSpecialCharIndex + 1));
                                i = endBraceIndex;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // if string following special character is a brace, include that text as welll
                            if (message.Substring(nextSpecialCharIndex + 1, 1) == "{")
                            {
                                int endBraceIndex = message.IndexOf('}', i);
                                if (endBraceIndex == -1)
                                {
                                    messages.Add(message.Substring(nextSpecialCharIndex));
                                    i = message.Length;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    messages.Add(message.Substring(nextSpecialCharIndex, endBraceIndex - nextSpecialCharIndex + 1));
                                    i = endBraceIndex;
                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Just submimt special character + next character
                                messages.Add(message.Substring(nextSpecialCharIndex, 2));
                                i = nextSpecialCharIndex + 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        #if DEBUG
            StringBuilder checkResult = new StringBuilder();
        #endif

            // need STA thread for Clipboard
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => {
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.Count; i++)
                    {
        #if DEBUG
                    Trace.WriteLine($"{i}: '{messages[i]}'");
                    checkResult.Append(messages[i]);
        #endif

                        // check if message has special character
                        if (messages[i].IndexOfAny(specialChars) == -1)
                        {
                            // no...send via "FAST" clipboard method
                            try
                            {
                                Clipboard.SetText(messages[i]);
                                SendKeys.SendWait("^V");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
        #if DEBUG
                                Trace.WriteLine("Clipboard Failure {ex.Message}");
        #endif
                                // clipboard failure, revert to SendKeys...
                                SendKeys.SendWait(messages[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // yes...send via SENDKEYS
                            SendKeys.SendWait(messages[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });

                thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                thread.Start();
                thread.Join();

        #if DEBUG
            Trace.WriteLine($"Original: {message}");
            Trace.WriteLine($"CHECK   : {checkResult.ToString()}");
            Debug.Assert(checkResult.ToString() == message, "Messages do not match!");
        #endif

        }
```

Comment: You say you can't use `SendKeys`, but you're using it all over the place. Parts of your question are unclear. Could you try to clarify?

Comment: I can't use SendKeys.Send, SendKeys.SendWait works. I'd prefer not to rely on SendKeys at all due to performance/reliability concerns, but I think it's only option right now to send keyboard input for me.

Comment: Right. So the current code works, but you want to get rid of the entire `SendKeys` dependency. Excellent premise, I'm sure we can work with that :-)

Comment: Yes, if it's possible. Or at least simplify/improve the performance. Currently I am using the hyprid copy/paste+SendKeys.SendWait to improve performance vs SendKeys.SendWait on its own. Looking at this code I feel there are so many potential unexpected places for this to go wrong ;)

Comment: I'm not familiar with this construct: `message = message.sak;jmas;kjdReplace("{ENTER}x", "\r\n");`, is there a typo in your code?

Comment: Must be issue when pasting code, I'll fix

Comment: I take it the application is not owned/written by you that receives the typed in data?

Comment: Could something like this help your sending application? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10057664/2557128

Answer (score 4):

### Conditional code in Debug

There is an alternative for using this pattern:

> ```
> #if DEBUG
>     Trace.WriteLine($"Clipboard Failure {ex.Message}");
> #endif
> ```

Use [Debug.WriteLine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline?view=netframework-4.8) instead. Much of you code could be simplified replacing `Trace.WriteLine` with `Debug.WriteLine` so you don't require the *preprocessor directive* `#if DEBUG`.

```
Debug.WriteLine($"Clipboard Failure {ex.Message}");
```

Comment: I think it also worth mentioning that `Trace.WriteLine` is decorated with `[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("TRACE")]` so it depends on what kind of output is required but I admit, wrapping `TRACE` by `DEBUG` is definitely wrong.